# Teechart Crashes and provide access violation message

Tags: activex, teechart

Getting This error while plotting a chart using teechart control.

[image]

Comment: Please provide more detailed information about your charting application and the circumstances in which the error occurs. Also, please send us a simple example project we can run "as-is" to reproduce the problem here. You can post your files at http://www.steema.net/upload/

Comment: Sorry can't share the code the following issue is encountered when u have less RAM available it throws this error continuously.

Comment: No need to send your production code. It would be very helpful if you could arrange a simple example project reproducing the issue though. Otherwise, without this information, we will hardly be able to suggest any solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Message normally comes when the system doesn't have resource such as memory, GDI object to draw the chart